# What is the sheaf of endomorphisms?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory

I saw this term or symbol “End$(\mathcal{F})$", where $\mathcal{F}$ is a quasi-coherent sheaf, in some places, e.g. [First Ext group of a sheaf](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/73003/first-ext-group-of-a-sheaf). But I found nothing on Google when I typing "sheaf of endomorphisms". So, can someone give me the definition. Thanks.

Comment: Try googling "sheaf hom" instead

Comment: You can find that $Hom_{\mathcal{O}_X} (\mathcal{F}, \mathcal{F})$ is a sheaf of modules in almost any algebraic geometry book.

Comment: Thanks. I do know "sheaf hom"

Comment: The sheaf of endomorphisms is just sheaf hom with the domain and codomain equal.